# Content security policy for frame. frame-src vs frame-ancestors

Tags: content-security-policy

What do `frame-src` and `frame-ancestors` do exactly? The definition shows the purpose is the same to define valid contents for frames for both directives.
When to use which one? I was able to load an external domain content in `iframe` using -

1. `frame-ancestors` and `default-src` rules
2. `frame-src`

Both are working but couldn't get correct use cases.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`default-src`, `frame-ancestors`, and `frame-src` are all part of the [Content-Security-Policy response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

## frame-src

Restricts what domains and page can load in an `iframe`.

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) `frame-src` directive specifies valid sources for nested browsing contexts loading using elements such as `<frame>` and `<iframe>`.

**For example:** If the website at `https://example.com` has a response header of `Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self'`, it can only load `https://example.com` inside `iframes`.

## frame-ancestors

Restricts what domains and page can be loaded in from an `iframe` (similar to the `X-Frame-Options` header, [but takes precedence over it](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options)).

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) `frame-ancestors` directive specifies valid parents that may embed a page using `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`, or `<applet>`.

**For example:** If the website at `https://example.com` has a response header of `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'`, it can only *be loaded* inside `iframes` from `https://example.com`.

## default-src

Acts as the default value for any **fetch** directive that isn't explicitly set ([here is a list of all fetch directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#fetch_directives))

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) `default-src` directive serves as a fallback for the other CSP fetch directives. For each of the following directives that are absent, the user agent will look for the `default-src` directive and will use this value for it.

**For example:** `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'` will default to the value `'self'` for all fetch directives. Other directives will be unaffected.

*Note: since `frame-ancestors` is not a fetch directive, setting `default-src` won't restrict it. It needs to be set separately.*

Comment: What happens when policy of the main page and child page conflicts?

Comment: The most restrictive policy would take precedence. So if a parent has a `frame-src` of `'none'` and tries to load an iframe that doesn't have a Content Security Policy, browsers that support this directive won't allow the iframe to load. Similarly, if a parent allows any domains to be loaded in iframes, but it tries to load a website that has a `frame-ancestors` of `'none'` in an iframe, browsers would prevent it from being embedded in the iframe.

Comment: It's worth being clear that default-src only defaults the values of fetch directives. This is mentioned in the quoted text in the answer above but isn't clear imho. Consult the latest CSP spec for a full list of fetch directives, at time of writing they are: child-src,
connect-src,
default-src,
font-src,
frame-src,
img-src,
manifest-src,
media-src,
prefetch-src,
object-src,
script-src,
script-src-elem,
script-src-attr,
style-src,
style-src-elem,
style-src-attr,
worker-src

Comment: @GreatSeaSpider thanks for the clarification, I just updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

frame-ancestors allows you to specify what parent source may embed a page.
frame-src, which allows you to specify where iframes in a page may be loaded from.